# Kendo Paging with Linq to SQL Classes, Query All Data Very Slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, kendo-grid

i am using kendo grid with "linq to sql classes".

**C# Linq query:**

```
    public DataSourceResult GetCustomer(Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return new DataLayer.MainDataContext().Customer()
            .Where(x => x.IsActive)
            .ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request);
    }
```

Assume customer data active is 1 million, then the above code will take 1 million data, then convert to ToDataSourceResult(from 'request'). In the result is true. Because this query show 10 data from "request"(DataSourceRequest). But in the process is the wrong, because in the background query take 1 million data first, then convert to ToDataSourceResult. Consequently my application very slow to display the data.

Then i am change my code:

```
    public DataSourceResult GetCustomer(Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return new DataLayer.MainDataContext().Customer()
            .Where(x => x.IsActive)
            .Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize)
            .ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request);
    }
```

The result is very fast to show data because query take 10 row data.
But the problem:
(1) The grid only displays the results in the bottom right "1-10 of 10 items", but there are 1 million items (rows of data).
(2) Total Paging only "Page 1", not exists 2, 3 and next.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Total on the returned DataSourceResult.

Comment: could not. if set the Total on the returned DataSourceResult, Grid Filter will not work. I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late but the problem is that you're calling .ToList() and that executes the query against the database and the result is then converted to DataSourceResult. ( I had the very same issue today.)

The correct way is like this:

```
public DataSourceResult GetCustomer(Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return new DataLayer.MainDataContext().Customer()
        .Where(x => x.IsActive)
        .ToDataSourceResult(request);
}
```

The extension method does the query with the specified sort, filter and page from the request parameter of the action.